# Sakai 2.10.5 used in job search

Tags: portfolio, sakai

I'm trying to find out if Sakai 2.10.5 portfolio can be used to help a student find employment?  What would the university have to do to get this up and running?  How to restructure Sakai for this end goal?

Answer (score 1):

Not sure to which you are referring, can you help us help you?

The current version of the Sakai LMS is 10.5.

The Open Source Portfolio (OSP), as it was, is in the process of being deprecated https://confluence.sakaiproject.org/display/OSP/Project+--+Portfolio (and I think its version number matched Sakai, making 2.9 the last release??)

And there's the exciting new Karuta ePortfolio project https://www.apereo.org/projects/karuta (which one could call Sakai ePortfolios 2 as a short hand).

Are one of those three applications what you were asking about?

Comment: Thank you for responding.  What we are trying to do is look into helping our students create a portfolio, perhaps on Sakai, or if other schools have a better way, to help in their job search.  We want to see if we can set up a way in which perspective employers can view their portfolios.  Have any other higher ed schools gone through this process, either using Sakai or other ways?  That is my query.